# Adding Pronumerals together in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I want javascript to be able to interpret the following (`a` and `b` are always going to be different, so these are just an example)

```
a=(3x)+y  
b=x+(4y)
```

and return the following

```
a+b=(4x)+(5y)
```

all variables are strings and not integers so math can not be applied to `a`,`b`,`x` or `y`

I have not started on this particular instance, due to the fact that i don't know where to start.

P.S. I have not had any experience with jQuery, so if possible, try and avoid it

EDIT: The program is designed to help find raw materials in the game minecraft. For example if you want a diamond sword (`a`) and a diamond pickaxe (`b`), `a` requires 1 wood (`x`) and 2 diamonds (`y`), and `b` requires 1 wood (`x`) and 3 diamonds (`y`). Once i run it through this program, i would like a response saying that it requires 2 wood and 5 diamonds. Sorry for any prior confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's program three little helper functions:

```
// exprToDict("3x + y") -> {x:3, y:1}
function exprToDict(e) {
    var d = {};
    e.replace(/(\d+)\s*(\w+)|(\w+)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
        d[$2 || $3] = parseInt($1 || 1);
    });
    return d;
}

// addDicts({x:1, y:2}, {x:100, y:3}) -> {x:101, y:5}
function addDicts(a, b) {
    var d = {};
    for(var x in a) d[x] = a[x];
    for(var x in b) d[x] = (d[x] || 0) + b[x];
    return d;
}

// dictToExpr({x:1, y:2}) -> x + (2 y)
function dictToExpr(d) {
    var e = [];
    for(var x in d)
        if(d[x] == 1)
            e.push(x);
        else
            e.push("(" + d[x] + " " + x + ")");
    return e.join(" + ")
}
```

Once we've got that, we're ready to code the main function:

```
function addThings(a, b) {
    return dictToExpr(
        addDicts(
            exprToDict(a),
            exprToDict(b)
    ))
}
```

Let's test it:

```
sword = "(3 wood) + diamond"
pickaxe = "wood + (2 diamond)"

console.log(addThings(sword, pickaxe))
```

Result:

```
(4 wood) + (3 diamond)
```

In order to process more than two things, modify `addDicts` to accept arrays:

```
function addDicts(dicts) {
    var sum = {};
    dicts.forEach(function(d) {
        for(var x in d)
            sum[x] = (sum[x] || 0) + d[x];
    });
    return sum;
}
```

and rewrite `addThings` to be:

```
function addThings(things) {
    return dictToExpr(
        addDicts(
            things.map(exprToDict)));
}
```

Example:

```
sword = "(3 wood) + diamond"
pickaxe = "wood + (2 diamond)"
house = "10 wood + iron"


console.log(addThings([sword, pickaxe, house]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am unable to implement this into my code, it is not returning a value into my HTML page. Secondly, does this support say, if something was made from 3 things, not just 2 and if there is more than 2 items you want to add, thanks, nice logic too, it seems like quite a reasonable approach

Comment: I am getting this error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined website

Comment: @VikeStep: regarding more than 2 things - see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, parse the input string - according to your grammar - to an object to work with:

```
function parseLine(input) { // pass a string like "a=(3x)+y"
    var parts = input.split("=");
    if (parts.length != 2) return alert("Invalid equation");
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        var summands = parts[i].split("+");
        parts[i] = {};
        for (var j=0; j<summands.length; j++) {
            summands[j] = summands[j].replace(/^\s*\(?|\)?\s*$/g, "");
            var match = summands[j].match(/^(-?\d*\.?\d+)?\s*([a-z]+)$/);
            if (!match) return alert("Parse error: "+summands[i]);
            var mul = parseFloat(match[1] || 1);
            if (match[2] in parts[i])
                parts[i][match[2]] += mul;
            else
                parts[i][match[2]] = mul;
         }
    }
    return parts;
}
// example:
parseLine("a=(3x)+y")
// [{"a":1},{"x":3,"y":1}]
```

Then, apply an algorithm for solving [linear equation systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) on it. I leave the implementation of that to you :-)

Comment: hmmm. i guess i have to clarify one more thing, a=(3x)+y is not a string in total, a is a variable and its value is (3x+y), catch my drift. I guess what i think might work is to get a+b to return (3x)+y+x+(4y) and then implement an algorithm to solve it, but idk how to do any of these. Sorry about the confusion and thanks for the time put into that code

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you're question has so radically changed that I'll write a completely new answer:

You can just use objects for that. Store the materials needed for the tools in key-value-maps:

```
var diamondSword = {
    diamond: 2,
    stick: 1
};
var diamondPickaxe = {
    diamond: 3,
    stick: 2
};
```

An addition function is very simple then:

```
function add() {
    var result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        for (var item in arguments[i])
            result[item] = (result[item] || 0) + arguments[i][item];
    return result;
}
// usage:
add(diamondSword, diamondPickaxe)
// {"diamond":5, "stick":3}
```